# Make template a valid Perl file

Tags: perl, preprocessor

I wrote my own Perl preprocessor—in Perl, of course.

I have a template file which contains valid Perl syntax except for statements like this

```
$VAR{ 'LABEL' } =
#include dir/PRECOMPILED.pl
;
```

where `PRECOMPILED.pl` contains an anonymous hash that was generated using Data::Dumper, e.g.

```
{
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
}
```

When I preprocess the template, it includes `PRECOMPILED.pl` into the template and generates a new file with valid Perl syntax.

Is there a good way to make the template lines above also a valid Perl program statement such that if the preprocessor is not run, I can check later in the program if $VAR{ 'LABEL' } has content?

For example

```
if( $VAR{ 'LABEL' } ){
    # do something
}
```

Comment: "Is there a good way to make the template lines above also a valid perl program statement such that if the preprocessor is not run..." `$VAR{'LABEL'} = ;` is not a valid Perl statement, so you will always get a syntax error if you don't run your preprocessor. In general, it's not a great idea to generate Perl code in the first place. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Speed. The precompiled portion are large yaml files converted into perl data structures.The yaml files contain statements that are interpreted by perl program, so that there are two levels of code generation. Other developers just edit yaml files and the script brings everything automagically together.

Comment: Are you referring to perl's `-P` command-line option that allowed you to put the Perl source through the C preprocessor as a first pass? [perl5120delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/perl5120delta.html) says ***"Perl's command-line switch "-P", which was deprecated in version 5.10.0, has now been removed."***, so it's an unsupported feature that was deprecated nine years ago and removed six years ago. You should find a better way. I suggest that your data should just decode your YAML files on the fly, or perhaps create a proper Perl module

Comment: I wrote my own perl preprocessor. In perl, of course. If I use on the fly approach, the program takes 3-4 longer.

Comment: @user2585500: I guess they're sizeable YAML files then. Have you tried [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS), which is likely to be much faster? I suggest you preprocess your YAML to Perl modules as I said, and simply `use` them instead of involving your preprocessor. It's beginning to sound like a permanent database is in order, which would have only a tiny impact on startup time and no import at all

Comment: Actually, I just found out that this works (still learning how to edit posts): \n  $VAR{ 'LABEL' } = ( \n
    #include dir/PRECOMPILED.pl \n
    )[0];

Comment: Thank you all. Will try modules route.

Comment: I'm sorry to offer an [*If I were you, I wouldn’t start from here*](https://simonkidd.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/if-i-were-you-i-wouldnt-start-from-here/) solution, but I'm an analyst!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) statement:

```perl
$VAR{LABEL} = do {
#include dir/PRECOMPILED.pl
};
```

But this solution has the side effect (if it matters): `do` creates a new scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that:

```
$VAR{ 'LABEL' } = (
#include dir/PRECOMPILED.pl
)[0];
```

also works.